# How has get2DPlotRange changed in 11.2?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Different results from `get2DPlotRange` in this example.

```
bc = BarChart[{1, 10, 56, 31},
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
      NumberForm[1000000 #1, DigitBlock -> 3,
       NumberSeparator -> ","], After] &),
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 18}, {0, 0}},
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}},
  Ticks -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
  PlotRange -> {All, {0.5, 4.5}}];

Charting`get2DPlotRange[bc]
```

**Version 11.1.1**

> ```
> {{0., 74.}, {0.0975965, 4.9024}}
> ```

**Version 11.2**

> ```
> {{0, 19}, {0, 1}}
> ```

Comment: By the way, I realise I can obtain the width, 74 from `Max[{1, 10, 56, 31}] + 18`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[
 bc /. HoldPattern[PlotRange -> _] -> PlotRange -> All]

(*  {{0., 74.}, {0.0975965, 4.9024}}  *)
```

Maybe you can check whether it is `BarChart` that has changed.  It seems its setting of `PlotRange` confuses the underlying function computing the range of the graphics (which returns a default `{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}`; for example:

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[bc, False] (* 2nd arg = include padding? *)

(*  {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}  *)
```

Comment: `Options[bc, PlotRange]` returns `{PlotRange -> {{All, All}, {0.5, 4.5}}}` both in version 11.2.0 and 11.1.1.